# Using Lambda expression with List.ConvertAll

Tags: c#, lambda

I am pretty new to C# and as a practice exercise was trying to convert a console input of Y's and N's into boolean array of true and false (Y=true N=false).

[image]

I get the "*Only assignment call, increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement*" error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
bool[] tempArray = Console.ReadLine().ToList().ConvertAll(ch => Char.Equals(ch, 'Y')).ToArray();
```

Lambdas do not need the type of their parameters to be specified in the declaration, they are inferred automatically. You would also need to convert to the list of `bool`s to an array with `ToArray`.

Comment: Something else that is inferred automatically: generic type arguments. You don't need either the `<char>` or `<bool>` here.

Answer (score 1):

This works and is a bit simpler.

```
var array = Console.ReadLine().Select(x => x == 'y');
```

I believe it is because you are working with a list and an array. That was the error I got when trying your method.

Comment: Nope, that will be `IEnumerable<bool>`. Also you don't need `ToArray<char>` for string.

Comment: So keep the var and add ToArray(). But why bother when 99/100 times an IEnumerable will do the trick? I mean it is a LINQ question after all.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool[] tempArray = Console.ReadLine().Select(ch => ch == 'Y').ToArray();
```

Comment: Just curious, why a byte array?

Answer (score 0):

To make it error-free:

```
var bools = Console.ReadLine().Where(x => Char.ToUpperInvariant(x) == 'Y' || Char.ToUpperInvariant(x) == 'N').Select(x => x == 'Y');
```